# Upgrade php5-gd to 2.0.1 on 12.04?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm working with the GD library for image manipulation, to which I need to create some transparent PNGs. Instead, I'm getting a black background. I've looked everywhere on how to generate a blank, transparent PNG canvas with it and all the answers just don't work for me.

On further inspection, I'm working with an old GD version:

[image: gd version info - 2.0]

The functions needed to create a transparent PNG require 2.0.1 although 2.0.28 or later is recommended. I installed `php5-gd` with `apt-get`, and aptitude hasn't found new packages.

Do I have to add a new PPA? Where can I find it? What about forcing a version?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-gd You should have libgd 2.0.36 in Ubuntu 12.04. I believe the "2.0" there is just a major/minor version and isn't sharing with you the patch level. Perhaps something else is going wrong.